# Plotting 2d array with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got two 1d arrays x and t which are making a grid and 2d array z on this grid.
 `z[i][j]` stands for `z(t[i], x[j])`. How to plot this surface with **pyplot**?

Comment: I simply can't understand python docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the 1d arrays, create a 2d meshgrid, and use `plt.surface()`.

```
# Make sure all necessary libraries are loaded
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Initialize 3d figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# create meshgrid
T, X = np.meshgrid(t, x)

# plot
ax.plot_surface(T, X, Z)
```

You can see a more complicated and complete example of a surface plot in the [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html)